# draw rectangle on a picture from pixels coordinates

Tags: java, android, paint, android-canvas

with the following code i can draw a rectangle on my bitmap image.

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
publishProgress(80);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
publishProgress(85);
canvas.drawRect(200, 100, 200, 100, paint);
bitmap.recycle();
channel.close();
```

i've read that the values given in `canvas.drawRect(200, 100, 200, 100, paint);` represent respectively left x, top y, right x and bottom y.  So my questions are :

- are those values in pixels? ppi or what??
- how can i draw a rectangle on my image if i have only the coordinates of each corners in pixels as shown on the picture below ?  assuming that i have A (x, y) B (x, y), C(x, y) and D(x, y) with x and y expressed in pixels from the axes of the picture below.
  NB: i don't have control on A,B,C,D they are given to me from a web service

  [image: rectangle i want to draw]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have a problem here, you would just do this:

canvas.drawRect(a.getX(), a.getY(), c.getX(), c.getY(), paint);

Yes the values are in pixels however your origin (0,0) is the top left of the canvas normally. Y value becomes more positive as you move down the canvas.

Comment: so i if i understand in get a.getX() i have to give the coordinates of  A?? like A( x, y)

Comment: You say you are given A, B, C and D from a web service? What do they look like? Are you actually given 8 numbers? 

The draw rectangle function essentially works out your 4 points when you give it 2 because you actually only have 4 unique values.

What I mean by that is that A and B both have the same Y co-ordinate. as do D and C. A and D have the same X co-ordinate, likewise B and C do.

Because of this you only need to tell the canvas the top left and bottom right co-ordinates of you rectangle and it will work out the rest.

Comment: Actually they are given to me by xml rpc so i need first extract values by parsing. This is xml from which i extract the values :    <Rectangle>
        <PixelCoordinatesType>
          <x>100</x>
          <y>200</y>
        </PixelCoordinatesType>
        <PixelCoordinatesType>
          <x>100</x>
          <y>200</y>
        </PixelCoordinatesType>
        <PixelCoordinatesType>
          <x>100</x>
          <y>200</y>
        </PixelCoordinatesType>
        <PixelCoordinatesType>
          <x>100</x>
          <y>200</y>
        </PixelCoordinatesType>
      </Rectangle>

Comment: i know the canvas needs only 4 values, that's why i have a problem. My question is how transform those 8 values in the 4 that the canvas needs

Comment: Yes, and my answer told you how to do that.
Pass it this:

X value of A, Y value of A, X value of C, Y value of C

Comment: Also as a side note if you use those values above all you will get is a single pixel drawn at (100,200)

Comment: this is just an example of how will be the xml, not that the coordinates wold those ones. The coordinates will be real ones where threats will be found on a  road... anyway thx i've found two ways to do it, i've seen my math teacher and i had another idea

Comment: Awesome answer, I could not figure out Canvas (0,0) points, your answer gave me that... thanks